# Generating an image inside a div in an each function with jQuery

Tags: jquery, appendto

```
$.each(data.items, function(i, pic) {
    $('<img/>').attr('src', pic.image).appendTo($("#wrap .images"));
});
```

How can I get to have that `<img/>` inside a div with a class of "img-wrap"?

EDIT  for clarification:
I would actually like to have EACH  itself inside an independant div with a class of img-wrap, I have a json request getting me quite a random amount of images each time and I want to have them in a div.

Comment: And where you would like to plug in these divs?

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this, if the div tag and img tag exist, retrive them instead of creating them:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.setAttribute("class", "img-wrap");

var img = document.createElement('img');
img.setAttribute("src", pic.image);

div.appendChild(img);

yourHolder.appendChild(div);
```

//Henrik

Comment: The OP has jQuery, use of browser-native DOM manipulation is not necessary.

Comment: I can agree on that, but its an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

This should be very simple as follows:

```
$.each(data.items, function(i, pic) {
   $('.img-wrap').append('<img src="'+pic.image+'"/>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".img-wrap").wrapInner('<div />')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the html and then adding it to the existing html within the div:

```
> var innerHtml = "<img src = " + pic.image + "/>";
> $(".img-wrap").html($(".img-wrap").html() + innerHtml);
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone ever wants to do what I needed to do, then this is what worked:

```
$.each(data.items, function(i, pic) {
    $('<img/>').attr('src', pic.image).appendTo($("<div/>").attr('class', 'img-wrap').appendTo($("#wrap .images")));
});
```

Comment: I thought you asked for *inside a div with a class of "img-wrap"*...?